# Event-based communication with an AngularJS BackgroundServicesApp on a seperate HTML document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, design-patterns, promise

Scenario:

I'm building an AppGyver Steroids **mobile web app**.

I chose to build a **Multi Page Application** using **multiple WebViews** to display parts of my app, because that way I can use native tabs, header bars and page transitions.

My JavaScript framework is AngularJS.
Since **every WebView has its own DOM and JavaScript runtime**, my AngularJS services are no unique singletons. This creates problems.

Appgyver [suggests](https://academy.appgyver.com/categories/4-app-architecture/contents/45-sharing-data-between-multiple-webviews) to load a hidden backgroundServices.html document as an always-there master document and house the singletons in my app there.

They provide a publisher/subscriber method using

> window.postMessage("someMessage");

and

> window.addEventListener("message", someMethod);

to **communicate between WebViews**.

Unfortunately they provide no example of this method and I'm really struggling to build a clean implementation.

Since I'm using **Restangular** I would like my REST services (that should be in backgroundServices) to return **promises**, and I can't figure out how to do that in a reusable way with a publisher/subscriber mechanism in between, without causing too much overhead..

**How can I communicate with an AngularJS service only accessible using Events, and keep working with Promises?**

I figure I need to make a "BackgroundServiceConnector" service available on every normal webview.

In this Service I would have a function

> call(serviceName, function, parameters)

which I call like this:

```
var app = angular.module('homeApp', ['ngTouch', 'BackgroundServiceConnectorApp']);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, backgroundServiceConnector) {

    $scope.doLogin = function(username, password){

        backgroundServiceConnector("accountService", "authenticate", {username: username,password: password})
        .then(function(){ 
            //login OK logic  
        }, function(error){
            //login Not OK logic
        });
    }
});
```

I think I'm more or less capable of implementing this, but I am unsure of:

1. how to make this usable for functions that do not return promises. (detect if the function returns a promise at the backgroundServices.html side)
2. if there isn't a more elegant way in which I don't have to pass "accountService" and "authenticate" as strings.
3. how I can - in the backgroundServices.html - parse the service name and function into an executable call.
4. how would I go about making the foreground services automatically "subscribe" to changes in the "model" at the background?

I know enough JavaScript to know it is a very extensible language offering a lot of freedom, but I don't know enough to be able to build a good solution for my scenario..

I would love for someone to help **point me in the right direction** and provide advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I would start looking at $broadcast, probably from the rootScope. Using this, you can listen from every module

Comment: That won't work because every page has its own rootScope. Every WebView has its own DOM and JavaScript runtime and the only means of sending a message between them is window.postMessage

Comment: You mean every WebView has it's own ngApp directive, and not only one for the entire page? Then yeah, a "global" pub-sub module is the solution, for each every WebView needs to subscribe/listen much like you described. Then to absorb it to your individual angularJs code, you will need to use $scope.apply when your listener receives a message from this window.addEventListener method that you define

Comment: service returns a promise and `postMessage`s, background page gets the message and makes the request, when it's done it sends a message back to the foreground service which in turn resolves the promise with the value.

Comment: I started making something but it didn't work out. I feel like I'm doing a lot of manual things that could be figured out by javascript wizardy.. reflection and such. I might give it another try in my spare time but I cannot spend more office time on this, unfortunately :(